# Create Store_view check box on the grid - Magento

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I noticed that the Product Catalog, there is an equal housing image to select the store view, it would be very useful in my case, however I do not find how to add this in my GRID.

[image: Store Choose]

Could you tell me how to do this?
Thank you

**@EDIT**
[image]

Just trying to be clearer, when used multistore in catalog_product page is shown a drop down box with all the store, I need to do the same, but on a custom page of my module.

Comment: You mean you want to show the drop down option to select your store view in your product catalog?

Comment: I think I went a little inconclusive in explaining. I need to do what is on the page of Product Catalog (like shown in the picture) in my custom page of a module.

Comment: The select drop down right?

Comment: That's right, Drop down with store view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood you want the drop down box to show the list of all stores. Then you need the source model of `adminhtml/system_config_source_store`

This is what you need and/or what you could do. Create a `system.xml` in the module you created. Add a field to it something like this.

```
<store_select translate="label comment">
    <label>Select Store</label>
    <frontend_type>Select</frontend_type>
    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_store</backend_model>
    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</store_select>
```

The other options is to create your own source model

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Store {
   public function toOptionArray() {
       return Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getStoreValuesForForm(false, true);
   }
}
```

And then replace the source model path of the `system.xml` with the one you just created.

EDIT:

[My Github](https://github.com/FerrazzzZ/magento1-research/tree/rs/061115_New_Admin_Page)

Checkout the commits with  message "091115 : Admin Controller Base". Again this is just the base where you could start. You still need to implement the logic for the select to work.

Comment: Not exactly I need = S
I edited my question to try to be a little clearer

Comment: @JoseEduardo This does exactly what you want and what you described. The code above gets all the stores available and puts them in dropdown list.

Comment: You need an controller action in your module to output it.

Comment: I could exemplify how I can do it, or come close to it?

Comment: Yes sure, let me get home. I'll update my answer as soon I replicate it my self.

Comment: Any progress in this regard? I am desperate because of deadlines

Comment: Hi, I just created a very basic base where you can start from. Check the updated answer with my github account. I recommend you to do via a block instead directly from the controller.

Comment: It worked perfectly with some adjustments, however how do i put it at the top of the page and not down?

And how can i get the value selected trough a controller?
Thank you

Comment: To add it to the bottom of the page you will to do some css styling.  Yes you can select a value through a controller. Check this post http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21045/pass-parameter-to-controller